# pca analysis using factominer and factoextra packages / libraries

Tags: r, dataframe, pca, tibble

```
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)

res.pca = PCA(clin.oc[,1:14], graph = TRUE)
scree = fviz_screeplot(res.pca, ncp=5, addlabels=TRUE, size=0.5, title='Scree 
plot')
loadings = plot(res.pca, choix = "var", title='Loadings')

n = fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", axes = 1, top = 5, title='Variable 
contributions')
scores = fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label="none", habillage=as.factor(clin), 
                      tittle='scores')
ggarrange(scree, loadings, n, scores)
```

[image]

and `ggarange` function wont work, says it is not found.

Comment: Is this the ggarrange from ggpubr? If so, ggpubr::ggarrange, or calling library(ggpubr) might help. Or similarly, "egg" if it's from egg.   
Also "title" is misspelt in fviz_pca_ind.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is already in res.pca because your 'identifier' variable is of type character.  Take those out (guess: PCA(clin.oc[,2:14], …).